# How do I install Anbox without breaking my system?

Tags: 16.04, anbox

Intel® Core™ i5-6300HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4 
16 GB ram
Nvidia 960m 
Currently on open source drivers but I've been on the proprietary before. Every time I install Anbox, it freezes my system towards the end of the installation, I fore shutdown and power back on, it freezes at the login screen. I've tried everything and the only fix I've found is a complete OS reinstall. Am I doing something wrong? I really want to get it working.